# Reading input by bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

In the bash [doc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_04.html) there is a statement:

> The shell reads its input from a file, from a string or from the
>   user's terminal

Can You provide some examples of each of these 3 options?

Comment: Good place to start: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html

Comment: Have you tried this at all? This reads like a homework exercise. Please show some effort in answering or researching answers to questions yourself before you post them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Input from a file: running a script (file with `.sh`extension)
2. Input from a string: `bash -c "ls -l"`
3. Input from terminal: well, any non-graphical Linux session.

If you are on a Linux with graphical environment, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and you'll see what I mean. (revert by cycling through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*</kbd> until you're back on graphical)

Comment: If i'm right that in the last third case (bash command alone) we create a subshell in which the future commands 'd be exdecuted?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's pretty straightforward:

```
bash hello.sh                     # From a file.
bash -c 'echo "Hello, world!"'    # From a string.
bash                              # From the terminal.
```

Cheers!

Comment: If i'm right that in the last third case (bash command alone) we create a subshell in which the future commands 'd be exdecuted?